# Web Services Quality Factors Cons

Tags: web-services, software-quality

Is there any disadvantages using web services affecting any of the quality factors...??
I found a lot of advantages of them like supporting interoperability and reusability.. but I don't find any cons of web services...

Answer (score 0):

The only disadvantage I can see is that it could allow your data to be used in ways you do not want. The interface has to be coded carefully so that you don't allow your data to be corrupted or misused by malevolent forces(hackers).

Since there is now audit trail back to those who have accessed your API and your data you should only expose the most innocuous data via your API.